# Angular routing - URL-injection security issue: what is the difference between redirectTo '' and '/'?

Tags: angular, security, google-search-console

Google Search Console says that a public website is attacked by hackers. The website is written in Angular 8.2.x. Hacked type: URL injection (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3311329?hl=en).

Sample URL-s under the warning:

- okt. 17. https://example.com/wiki.php?59gqp8q6r3cbb3081flf33607o0rhvr8
- aug. 27. https://example.com/wiki.php?2687fiugf121ce0u1k43m_8

That's pretty interesting since there is no any PHP source on the server at all. I started to debug... I opened one of the sample URL-s. Following happened: website is loading, I see that the content is rendered (home page), but the URL changed and it redirects me from

https://example.com/wiki.php?2687fiugf121ce0u1k43m_8

to

https://example.com/?2687fiugf121ce0u1k43m_8=

It cuts off some parts of the URL. Interesting, because I would expect that Angular routing redirects me to https://example.com if route was not found.

**Current route object:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

I tried out the same in localhost as well, happened the same.

**If I change redirectTo value from empty string to '/', then it redirects to the expected route (https://example.com).**

Does anybody have any idea what is happening in the background (regarding this URL injection issue) and what is the difference between `redirectTo: ''` and `redirectTo: '/'`? Does it seem to be my fault or is it a bug in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

If you use route starts with '/' then the router considers the route is absolute. Router starts searching from the root of the application.

If you use route ''  (without leading slash) then the router considers the route is relative. Relarive of current active route (before redirecting)

More informathin about this: https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation

Hope it helps!